# Trying to log into XMPP server using Smack results in SASL "not authorized"

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, sasl

I'm trying to use Smack to log into a XMPP server. When trying to login I get the following Error :

> SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized

I have been able to connect and log into the server using PSI-IM with the same credentials.

This is what I currently have :

```
    System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

    ConnectionConfiguration configuration = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.bla.com", 5223);
    configuration.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configuration.setSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());
    configuration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    configuration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    configuration.setServiceName("bla.net");

    Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(configuration);

    try {
        connection.connect();
        connection.login("user@bla.net", "blablabla");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the DummySSLSocketFactory I'm using : http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/spark/tags/spark_2_5_3_s/src/java/org/jivesoftware/spark/util/DummySSLSocketFactory.java

I'm thinking that the problem is that I need to select 'Legacy SSL' when connecting through PSI, I'm not sure howto do that in Java though.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `login()` without the domain part, i.e. `connection.login("user", "blablabla");`

Comment: it may be because of wrong user name or password.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `login()` **without** the domain part in the username:

```
connection.login("user", "password");
```

not

```
connection.login("user@example.org", "password");
```